# Add a custom label to the max price for Woocommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In WooCommerce, I should need to show all variation prices like in this site [koenigvineyards.com](https://www.koenigvineyards.com/shop/current-vintages/2014-chardonnay-bitner-vineyard/),
with the Min price and the **"Wine club price"** *(Max price)*.

How I can add a custom label before the Max price of a variable product in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a custom text label to the Max price of a variable product (like "Wine club price"), you can use this function hooked in **`woocommerce_format_price_range`** filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_price_range', 'custom_format_price_range', 10, 3 );
function custom_format_price_range( $price, $from, $to ) {
    $text_max = '<span class"wine-club-label">'.__( "Wine club price" ).': </span>';
    $price = sprintf( _x( '%1$s &ndash; %2$s', 'Price range: from-to', 'woocommerce' ), is_numeric( $from ) ? wc_price( $from ) : $from, is_numeric( $to ) ? $text_max . wc_price( $to ) : $text_max . $to );
    return $price;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.